# How to make acrylic/plastic effect with shader?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

[image]

I am studying texturization and found this reference image. I would like to know if anyone could help me replicate the material shown on this "rabbit-astronaut".

I already tried to map using images in PS, and even reflecting images but it did not look similar. This texture appears to be more opaque.

Comment: Have you tried to simply mix a Diffuse (a bit yellow or maybe it's the light which is yellow) and a Glossy shader?

Answer (score 1):

### Final

A little bit exaggerated to show the effect.

[image: Final]

### Material

I've used only **Principled BSDF** shader. Most important thing is to use **Rough** material (1.0) with **Clearcoat**. You can manipulate how much reflection will be visible by changing **Clearcoat value** and/or change **Clearcoat roughness** also.

[image: nodes]

### Lightning

I've used really simple setup without much of a thought for this example. 4 **Area Lamps** with different size, strength and **Blackbody** value (color).

[image: lights]

Comment: but if i want to use this texture on a game character? i woulndt have all those lighints above him. what happens if I remove these lamps and just use the global?

Comment: @SHRIMP please edit your question and add more information. What Game Engine are you willing to use? What does it mean "global"? HDRI lightning? Single color? If you want to see reflections you need lamps/environment. No matter what material/shader you will use. Or you can bake reflections. But again, please add more information of what exactly you want to achieve and where. For Blender you have an answer.

Comment: alright!  i ll add more details. just a moment